# Asp.net mvc 4 RedirectToAction slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I use `RedirectToAction("MyView", "MyController")` sometimes the redirection is very slow to render the destination view.

It doesn't always happen.

I am using ASP.net MVC4 with IIS7.5

How can I prevent this problem and speed up the redirection?

Comment: This isn't really enough information to go on. Are you doing anything on the page `/MyController/MyView` which could be causing the server to take a long time to process?

Comment: Question is interesting, but as @TimBLames sayed This isn't really enough information.

Comment: @TimBJames, not really.. most of my pages are simple (they don't use any database access).. As I said, it doesn't happen everytime.
I don't know if it's a IIS7 problem. Thanks

Comment: Intermittent problems could be due to network issues or if still under development, then the debugger can play a role, try starting the application with Ctrl+F5. I don't know if this applies in your case or not, but I prefer to use Return MyActionMethod as opposed to RedirectToAction(...) when I can as it saves a whole round trip over the wire.

Comment: @JTMon what do you mean by "Return MyActionMethod"? sorry if it's a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

I will put this here as code will not show very well in the comments section. If the action method you are redirecting to is in the same controller you are currently in, it is simpler and more efficient to call that method directly and return its results instead of the redirect response generated by the RedirectToAction method.  Just to make sure we are on the same page, RedirectToAction actually returns a redirect response (302) to the client asking it to issue a new request to the action method you have specified as per MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.108).aspx.  Some code to illustrate:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(){
    //do some work here
    Return View(MyModel);
}

public ActionResult ActionIAmCurrentlyIn(){
    //Do Soe work here
    return RedirectToAction ("MyAction", "MyController"); //This costs an extra trip across the wire
    return MyAction(); // Does same thing but without the extra trip to the client
}
```

This overhead of the extra trip becomes more significant if there are parameters being passed along to "MyAction" and as the network speed goes down.

Comment: Redirect updates the URL for the client.  This might be important.

Comment: @cadrell0 Yes it does. There are other reasons why one might choose to use RedirectToAction (I have at least 3 places where I use it in my last project) which is why in the original comment I stated that I am not sure if it is applicable in this situation or not. Just mentioned it because it does lead to a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

Responding as an answer because I don't have enough rep to add a comment...

@JTMon  In your code the "return MyAction();" can cause potential issues because the "MyAction" action will actually try to load a view named "ActionIAmCurrentlyIn" since that is the action that's specified in the route values (at least I assume that's where it's getting it from, I haven't actually dug into the code to find out).

This can be resolved by specifying the view name in MyAction:

```
 return view("MyAction", MyModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this problem and speed up the redirection use:

```
return Redirect("~/MyController/MyView");
```

This approach will not change client-server interaction.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RedirectToActionPermanent("View","Controller");` for it.

Comment: how will it create problems?